# mysql left join duplicate value need - row of that column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need help with querying two tables with a join I have 2 tables:

**table_a**

```
| id | name | 
------------- 
| 1  | a    |
```

**table_b**

```
| id | name |  lastname | cost | total |
----------------------------------------
| 1  |   a  |     b     | 100  | 200   |
| 2  |   a  |     c     | 100  | 200   |
```

`SELECT * FROM table_a left join table_b ON ( table_a.name = table_b.name )`

I need to get  output like below:

```
| id | name |  lastname | cost | total |
---------------------------------------
| 1  |   a  |     b     | 100  |  200  |
| 2  |   a  |     c     | 100  |   -   |
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What are you getting as result from your query, are you getting an error? And why do you expect the last "total" to be empty? seems to me it should be 200 instead.

Comment: it's requirement from customer i don't know why please. (T_T) 
it be 200 out put. but customer need "-" instead.

Comment: I'm not sure the examples provided make it clear what you expect in your results, astable_b already has the name column listed in table_a, so joining with table_a wouldn't accomplish anything. What's in table_a that needs to be in your results?

Comment: sorry for not clear examples please.
`table_a` 
`| bil_id | item_name |  item_price | ` 
`| a01    |      ring       |    100    | ` 
`| a01    |   bracelet   |    100    | ` 

`table_b`
`| bil_id |   total   |` 
`| a01    |   200  |` 

I need result like below.
`| bil_id | item_name |  total | ` 
`| a01    |      ring       |    200   | ` 
`| a01    |   bracelet   |     -       | `

Comment: Why the second row and not the first one? Because... it's `ID` is 2? There's something you are not telling.

Answer (score 0):

table_a 
`| bil_id | item_name | item_price |`
`| a01    | ring      | 100        |`
`| a01    | bracelet  | 100        |`

table_b 
`| bil_id | total |`
`| a01    | 200   |`

I need result like below. 
By sql join condition.

`| bil_id | item_name | total |`
`| a01    | ring      | 200   |`
`| a01    | bracelet  | -     |`

Answer (score 0):

try this query to your model for join tables mysql from codeigniter

`$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('table_b', 'table_a.id= table_b.id');
return $this->db->get('table_a')->result();`

Comment: Thank you for help it's difficult for query I solved by php `foreach`.